# How to pass hashmap<string, hashmap<string, string>> to a simple adapter?

Tags: android, hashmap, adapter, arrays

I have a simple adapter filling a `ListView` in this manner :

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist ,   
                    R.layout.itemlist, new String[] { "item1", "items2" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_id, R.id.item_title });
```

I adjust my code and have a `hashmap<string, hashmap<string,string>>` now and I cannot pass it to the `new string[]{"item1","item2"};`

How should I solve this?

Here is my XML structure:

```
<groups>
  <group>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <actions>
      <action>...</action>
      <action>...</action>
    </actions>
  </group>
  <group>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <actions>
      <action>...</action>
      <action>...</action>
      <action>...</action>
    </actions>
  </group>
  <group>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <actions>
      <action>...</action>
    </actions>
  </group>
</groups>
```

The code I had prepared but got stuck on was this:

```
public class ErrorCodeList extends ListActivity {

public static final String LANGUAGE = null;

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
public ListAdapter adapter;
public Dialog progDialog;
public ProgressBar progBar;
public TextView lblMessage;

private Intent myIntent;
private String  URLvariable;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    myIntent = getIntent();
    URLvariable = myIntent.getExtras().getString("urlType");

    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.activity_error_list, 
                    new String[] { "tid", "tname" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_id, R.id.item_title });

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                 

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ErrorCodeDetails.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("map",hashMap);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

    progDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.progress_dialog);
    progDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);

    progBar = (ProgressBar) progDialog.findViewById(R.id.progBar);
    lblMessage = (TextView) progDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtProgMessage);
    lblMessage.setText("Please Wait.....");

    progDialog.show();
    new GetDataTask().execute();        

}


private Boolean isOnline()  {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(ni != null && ni.isConnected())
        return true;

    return false;
}

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if(isOnline()){
            mylist.clear();                  
            }  

            // Start the http request
            String feedURL="http://...";        
            String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(feedURL);
            Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

            int numResults = 1;

            if((numResults <= 0)){
                Toast.makeText(ErrorCodeList.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                finish();
            }

            NodeList troubles = doc.getElementsByTagName("trouble");

            for (int i = 0; i < troubles.getLength(); i++) {                            
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

                Element e = (Element)troubles.item(i);
                if((e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue().equals("error"))) {
                    //map.put("id", "ID:" + Integer.valueOf(e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue()));
                    //map.put("status", "Status:" + (e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("status").getNodeValue()));
                    map.put("tid", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
                    map.put("tname", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
                    map.put("tdescription", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "description"));

                    mylist.add(map);
                }           
            }
            System.out.println(mylist);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(ErrorCodeList.this, "No connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        progDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

This was before I tried to nest the hasmaps.
Does this clarify my goal?

Comment: How should I do this do you have an example?

Comment: [see this tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: Thanks I will be reading this. I'm a newbie if it comes to android development, but what should be my focus within this tutorial to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `SimpleAdapter` takes a `List<Map<String, String>>`, not a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` as you have.

Is there a reason your inner `Map` needs to be contained by another `Map` instead of by a `List`? If not, you can just change the type. If so, you can use the following to extract a `List` of the inner `Map` objects:

```
asList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(outerMap.values());
```

---

Note: I assume your `Map` contains the data for each row in your list, as specified [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29). For example:

```
// Create an example row (you'd have many rows)
Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
row.put("author", "George Orwell");
row.put("title", "Nineteen Eighty-Four");
row.put("year", "1949");

// Create an example list of rows (this would contain many maps)
List<Map<String, String>> rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
rows.add(row);
```

`rows` would replace `myList` in your question above. You still have a `String[]` which would contain the keys from the `Map` (author, title, year) and you still have an `int[]` which would contain the resource IDs `View`s in the layout where the associated values should appear (e.g., a reference to `TextView`s in your XML layout like `R.id.author`, `R.id.title`, and `R.id.year`).

Comment: and then asList should be on the spot of new string[]{"item1","item2"};?

Comment: No, if `asList` contains the data for each item, then it would be the 2nd parameter (it would replace `mylist` in your question above). The 4th parameter `new String[]` has keys from the `Map`, the 5th parameter `new int[]` has resource IDs telling where that value goes.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is fill a ListView with the XML structure I will post in my question now. And from this XML fill a ListView when selecting a row in the ListView another activity will be created with a new ListView holding the information of the '<actions>' connected to the group it was selected from.